# Dynamics CRM - Add/Remove events from a custom made settings page

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

Hi awesome developers,

Maybe someone can help or put me in the right direction. I want to create a settings page with a few yes/no options.

These settings need to enable or disable form events from different entities. First I was thinking about creating a new entity named foo_Settings with a few fields and yes/no options to trigger on change events. These events will then add or remove events from another entity.

After doing some research, I couldn't find any examples or cases or any info if this could be done through webservices.

I hope someone can help :)

Greets,

Comment: Is the question, how do I programatically add onChange Events to fields on a form?

Comment: @Daryl Yes exactly, how do I add onChange events from code for different entities/forms. So not the **current** page or form.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a common design pattern in CRM to have a settings/configuration-entity for storing settings such as this.

You can decide to either have one settings-record per organization, or maybe one settings-record per business unit if that suits your needs better. In this way you can have different configurations depending on the need of each business unit.

After creating the settings record and adding some boolean fields, you would write javascript that runs OnLoad of specific entities. This code would fetch the relevant settings-record, read the value of the relevant boolean-field and add a change listener depending on the value of the boolean by calling [addOnChange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_12).

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed a way I could do it. AddOnChange() or RemoveOnchange() based on the values I am getting from an Odata Call. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334409(v=crm.5).aspx

Comment: Is there also a way to secure this settings page for just a few users in a role?

Comment: Secure?  You could use standard CRM security for the Settings entity.  Remember though, there is always God Mode to be aware of: http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2014/07/29/activate-god-mode-in-crm-2013---don-t-let-your-users-see-this

Comment: Lol, I've never heard of that before @Daryl. Thanks for the info!

Comment: What about performance? Imagine an Odata call for each onload (onupdate) per user at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about the settingspage and ways/solutions to create such functionality, there also was something that was itchy..

By creating a settings page and checking in the onload function of each entity with a fetch (odata call), this is not the most fastest or cleanest way. What if thousands of people are using a entity.. This will resulting that thousands of people will fetch.

So my solution will be:

Creating a settingspage (entity).. Onchange event of a setting will fire a odata call to set a record (true or false) on a hidden field in that entity..

In the onload of the entity I will check the value of that hidden field and do logic. This way I will prevent that there will be an Odata call every time the page loads..

Are there any other solutions?